# Underscore .reduce() returns NaN?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Should add all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5.

```
var sum = _.reduce( _.range(1, 1000), function(x, n) {
  if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) { return x+=n; }
}, 0);
```

I expect the output to be `233168` but I get `NaN`.

For some reason `sum` is not accepting the initialized value of `0`. However if I preface this with `var sum = 0;` then it works and returns the proper output of `233168`

Why doesn't it accept the initialized value?

Comment: What are you returning if the number is not a multiple of 3 or 5?

Comment: Just FYI, you can sum the multiples in a sequential range without a loop. It can be done with math only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the reducing function returns `undefined` when the conditional fails .. thus `x` evaluates to undefined (the last return value) in the subsequent invocation .. and undefined + a number is .. well, NaN.

Also, [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) is being used incorrectly; it should carry its own state. Compare it with:

```
var sum = _.reduce( _.range(1, 1000), function(x, n) {
  // Add n to the tally if it is a valid multiple..
  // (the returned value is used as the *next* value of x)
  if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) { return x + n; }
  // ..or simply return the current tally.
  else { return x; }
}, 0);
```

Note that the `sum` variable was *not* assigned from within the reducing function (it would have been overwritten by the outside assignment anyway). This keeps `reduce` a pure operation, not withstanding the occasional abuse of a mutable memo, truer to its [functional roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).